# print multiple text inputs in Shiny R every time they are added

Tags: r, shiny

I'm developing the Shinny App below but I have had such a hard time with the following:

When I add in the text box two names like **Magnolia_grandiflora**, and then **Magnolia_ovata**, I'd like the app to print these input names as following:

**Outgroups selected: Magnolia_grandiflora
Magnolia_ovata**

However, the app is printing only the last input name and erasing the first. I'd like the app to always print newly added names.

Also, how can I access a string (vector) of all such input names if I want to use them for something else in my app? For example, I will need the vector of all input names as an argument of another function.

Thank you very much!

Domingos

```
ui <- fluidPage(  
    sidebarPanel(
        textInput("outgroups", "Select outgroup taxa", ""),
        actionButton("addoutgroup", "Add"),
      
      br(),
      br(), 
     
    mainPanel(
      htmlOutput("text")
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$addoutgroup, {
    n <- isolate(input$addoutgroup)
    if (n == 0) return()
    # create n-th pair of text input and output
    output[[paste0("ui", n)]] <- renderUI(
      list(textInput(paste0("textin", n), isolate(input$outgroups)),
           textOutput(paste0("textout", n))))
    updateTextInput(session,"outgroups", value="")
  })
  
  output$text <- renderUI({
    str1 <- paste("Number of selected outgroups:", input$addoutgroup)
    str2 <- paste("Outgroups selected:", isolate(input$outgroups))
    HTML(paste(str1, str2, sep = '<br/>'))
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Domingos - could you describe a bit more about how you'd like your app to work? Did you want the user to enter species in a text box, one by one, and the app to store what was entered for future use? Is there other functionality you're trying to build into this as well?

Comment: Dear Ben, thanks for your interest in helping out. Yes, the user should enter species name in the text box, one by one, and the app should store the names (then, how can I access these names?). Also there is a line called "Outgroups selected:", where the app should be inserting each name of the entered species, like: "Outgroups selected: Magnolia_grandiflora". If the user type the second species, it should update as "Outgroups selected: Magnolia_grandiflora Magnolia_ovata". However, the app is always updating by the last entered name like "Outgroups selected: Magnolia_ovata".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working demo you can try.

I would consider using `reactiveValues` to store your inputted species names. In this case, you can have `rv$outgroup` be a vector that stores the names.

As a new names is entered, you can combine `c()` the currently stored `rv$outgroup` with the new name.

Then, later you can access all of the names in the vector as `rv$outgroup`.

Also note that I moved `mainPanel` in `ui` outside of `sidebarPanel`.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(  
  sidebarPanel(
    textInput("outgroups", "Select outgroup taxa", ""),
    actionButton("addoutgroup", "Add"),
    br(),
    br()
  ), 
  mainPanel(
    htmlOutput("text")
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  rv <- reactiveValues(outgroup = NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input$addoutgroup, {
    rv$outgroup <- c(rv$outgroup, input$outgroups)
    updateTextInput(session, "outgroups", value="")
  })
  
  output$text <- renderUI({
    str1 <- paste("Number of selected outgroups:", length(rv$outgroup))
    str2 <- paste("Outgroups selected:", paste(rv$outgroup, collapse = " "))
    HTML(paste(str1, str2, sep = '<br/>'))
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hi Ben! this is absolutely amazing solution! It is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much! :-)

Comment: Absolutely, thanks for reminding me about that. So, I have already marked it as solved question and upvoted too. Thanks once again! It was a big help indeed...